# How to 'connect' Anaconda's packages/modules to Sublimetext?

Tags: python, pandas, path, anaconda, sublimetext3

So, I downloaded `pandas_datareader` through Anaconda. When I try to use `pandas_datareader` it does not work, or the path is not correct.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'`

Earlier I tried to install Anaconda or connect Anaconda to `SublimeText3` through the Package Installer of SublimeText3 (<kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>).

I do not get it work. Searching further, I found a site that explains how to create an environment and install Anaconda, I already did that before.

http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/

So, it might be that I have a path linking issue. Can you help me out to understand this?

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall all packages and reinstall it.
if you are using extension remove all and add again.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it did not work. Do you might know what else I can do? SublimeText3 says: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deci\Desktop\python 01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'' '

Comment: Can I have your code please, so then I can tell you?

Comment: Okay, and thank you for responding back. The code is (shortend because of the allowed amount of characters: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Deci\Desktop\python 01.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Deci\Desktop\python 01.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\\Desktop]
[path: C:\Users\Deci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Deci\...\Python\Python37-32\; C:\Users\Deci\Anaconda3;C:\Python27\;]'

Comment: Does somebody else knows what to do?

Comment: You probably just installed the package for the wrong version of python. Make sure you are using the right pip. Usually the safest thing to do is to run: sudo python3 -m pip install pandas_datareader if you are trying to install the package for your python3 installation {pip install pandas_datareader}